# Angular custom validation directive - how to properly skip ng-disabled field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made myself a custom directive and it works fine but now I got a Form which has some disabled field with `ng-disabled`, I believe that I have to call up the `setTimeout` function since the `ng-disabled` could be happening after the fact but I'm not sure I coded it properly... is my code the correct way? I'm not sure if there's a special location to put the `setTimeout` piece of code, and I'm not even sure it is correct actually... but it does seems to work...so could someone validate and/or update my code if need be?

```
// Angular - custom Directive
directive('myDirective', function($log) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            validate = function(value) {
                .....
            }

            var validator = function(value) { 
                // invalidate field before doing validation 
                ctrl.$setValidity('validation', false); 

                elm.unbind('keyup').bind(keyup, function() {
                    // make the regular validation of the field value
                    var isValid = validate(value); // call validate method           
                    scope.$apply(ctrl.$setValidity('validation', isValid));            
                });  

                // for the case of field that might be ng-disabled, we should skip validation
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(elm.attr('disabled')) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('validation', true); 
                    }
                }, 0);

                return value;     
            };

            // attach the Validator object to the element
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
        }
    };
});
```

**EDIT**
I have to note that this piece of code is a really tiny part of my code, I only took the relevant part of it and yes at first look the `unbind('keyup')` doesn't make much sense unless you see the real code which is more like `unbind('keyup').bind(optionEvnt)`...which is actually giving an extra optional feature of choosing the event trigger you want to use on the validator and the default keyup was interfering when I was using `blur` event. In many Forms validation, I prefer to use the `blur` event so that's why it's an optional feature.

The real code is available on my [Github / Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation) and is available to everyone to use...Take a look and you'll probably love it enough to use it in your code :)

Comment: Chen-Tsu Lin...why do you keep adding `javascript` tag when the question is stricly related to AngularJS? You know there's other ways to get score then just adding tags everyday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of unnecessary code in there, unless I am missing what your actual intent is. This should work.

```
// Angular - custom Directive
directives.directive('myDirective', function($log) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

            var validate = function(value) {
                return (value === "valid");
            };

            var validator = function(value) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('validInput', validate(value));
                return value;
            };

            // attach the Validator object to the element
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);

            // Observe the disabled attribute
            attrs.$observe("disabled",function(disabled) {
                if(disabled){
                    // Turn off validation when disabled
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validation', true);
                } else {
                    // Re-Validate the input when enabled
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validation', validate(ctrl.$viewValue));
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it tonight...the `keyup` thing is not exactly the way I wrote it, my directive has a lot of features and 1 of the feature is to pass whichever event trigger you want, so my real code it's `elm.unbind('keyup').unbind(evnt).bind(evnt, function() {...}` and I had to unbind the keyup because it was causing me problem when I was using another type of event. I have a Github available to everyone, if you want to use it go ahead... https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation

Comment: BTW, I'm open to suggestions and code change on the Github as well, I'm at the early stage of learning Angular...thx

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, now I can comment everywhere! (something I am sure they will regret). As for your project, it looks great, would you be open to pull requests too?

Comment: Haha great for comments.. Yes I'm very open to pull request as I'd like to make it better for not just me but others to use as well..and as I said, I'm in very early stage of learning Angular, so having pull requests would help me in good ways :)  Out of curiosity, would you use the directive the way I've done it? I mean, I never seen anyone doing it the way I've done it (except PHP frameworks) and I'm not sure if it's good or not haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use angular's `$timeout` instead of javascript's native `setTimeout()` you'll have more luck, since `$timeout` lets angular know whats happening, what needs to be updated and all that. However I think the best solution for what you're looking to do is observing the disabled attribute of the directive, no need for timers and intervals:

```
attrs.$observe("disabled",function(value) {

if(value){

       ctrl.$setValidity('validation', true); 

}else{

       ctrl.$setValidity('validation', false); 

}});
```

Comment: Ah yes I always forget that Angular has it's own `$timeout` method..haha... Thanks for the code I'll try it out tonight after work.